# Git hooks doesn't work on SourceTree in Windows

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have SourceTree v3.4.15 running in windows 10. It does not run post-checkout in git\hooks when I check out a branch.
It works fine when I check out the branches via the terminal.
Any idea how I can fix the issue?

it runs well when I check out a branch from the terminal